# How to disable watch and share button on youtube videos using CSS/ Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-iframe-api

I want to disable watch and share buttons on youtube video using CSS / Reactjs. I am embedding youtube video in our application using ReactPlayer and tried to disable watch and share buttons by fetching the iframe and change the css classes pertaining to the buttons, I am able to fetch the iframe pertaining to the video. However, could not get reference to the elements in the #document which is part of the iframe to manipulate them.

I have gone through couple of posts and got to know that it is due to CORS.

Early we could achieve this by setting the config parameter showinfo=0 and rel=0. But now there are deprecated

Could someone help me on this.

Comment: did you find any solution ??

Comment: use this https://github.com/sampotts/plyr this is an example https://jsfiddle.net/uskbqgmh/

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly noticed from Youtube revision history showinfo parameter is deprecated as of September 25, 2018.
"Watch Later" and "Share" buttons were also part of this feature and they can't be removed.

Further you can never access/manipulate the dom-contents of iframe served from different source. Its like one web application having access to another application content.

Finally, the only hack I can suggest over here is you css `position: absolute; pointer-events: none;` for your dummy disabled share button and place it exactly over share icon of youtube player in your web application.

```
.overlay-banner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 560px; // width of video player
    height: 58px; // height of banner
    background: transparent;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
}
```

This overlay will prevent clicks on `share/watch` later icons. which can be bad user experience. Working [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/7o5wzva2/2/)

So, You can modify this`overlay-banner` css `background` with your custom background image or color and make it `display: block` only when video is in pause/complete state which you can fetch though Yotube api.

Hope this works. :)

Answer (score -2):

Add these query params for the youtube url

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/tFlAFo78xoQ?mode=opaque&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&wmode=transparent

Comment: showinfo : This parameter is deprecated and will be ignored after September 25, 2018.

Comment: share button is back when i click play button